Randomizability of a signature scheme and the DDH problem
I am currently studying the so-called PS-signature and its property of being randomizable. In short, a PS-signature on a message $m$ is a tuple $(h, h^{x+ym}) \in \mathbb{G_1}\times \mathbb{G_1}$, where $h \in \mathbb{G_1}$ is randomly sampled during signing and the pair $(x,y)$ is the signers secret key corresponding to the public key $(X=\tilde{g}^x, Y=\tilde{g}^y) \in \mathbb{G_2}\times \mathbb{G_2}$.
A key property is that such a signature can be simply randomized by raising both components to the same random non-zero power $t$, i.e. $(h^t, h^{t(x+ym)})$, which still verifies correctly. The authors state

One can note that a signature $\sigma = (\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ is randomizable, by raising both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ to a same non-zero power. The invariant is the discrete logarithm of $\sigma_2$ in basis $\sigma_1$, hence, the unlinkability relies on the DDH assumption.

Although it might be obvious, I am not able to give a precise reduction from DDH to the problem of linking a signature and its randomization. Can somebody help?

Clearly, unlinkability only makes sense with respect to an adversary that doesn't know the message (otherwise, the adversary can just verify the two signatures, and one is a re-randomization of the other if and only if they are both valid for the known message). So in order to challenge an adversary in the unlikability security game, it is fine to send them signatures without knowing the associated messages.
Then, given a tuple $(g,g',h,h')\in\mathbb{G}_1^4$, both $(g,g')$ and $(h,h')$ happen to be valid signatures on some messages (which we do not know without solving a discrete log problem but that's ok). The important point is that those messages are the same (i.e., the signatures are re-randomizations of each other) if and only if the 4-tuple is a DDH tuple. The reduction follows directly from that observation.
